# IIS changes Kestrel binding to dynamic port addresses

Tags: c#, iis, kestrel-http-server

I have an ASP.Net Core console app that is being run through IIS. At startup, it configures Kestrel and it should bind to a specific port address (ie. http://localhost:6500). However, when deployed on IIS, the log shows that it's binding to a different (dynamic) address because the `PreferHostingUrls` is set to true. The exact wording in the log says:

`Overriding endpoints defined in UseKestrel() because PreferHostingUrls is set to true. Binding to address(es) 'http://127.0.0.1:36783' instead.`

I have tried several attempts to set this value to false and I have searched and searched on how to bind Kestrel to a specific port using `UseUrls` variable in my code or by setting environment variables. And yet, nothing I do will allow me to bind kestrel to port 6500. So, here's my question(s):

1. Does anyone know how to set the `PreferHostingUrls` value to false so that IIS will allow me to set the binding through my code?
2. If I can't bind to a static port address, does anyone know how to retrieve the dynamic port address that was used so I can use that to launch a child process?

Here's how I'm setting up the Host and Kestrel:

```
int port = 6500;
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        var b = webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
        {
            // Handle requests up to 50 MB
            options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 52428800;
            options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, port);
        })
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseUrls("http://localhost:6500")
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .PreferHostingUrls(false)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
        .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) => {
             logging.AddNLog(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        });
                    
        if (port > 0)
        {
            b.UseUrls($"http://localhost:{port}");
            b.PreferHostingUrls(false);
            ComputeChildren.ParentPort = port;
         }
     }).Build();
```

My **web.config** file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath=".\myApplication.exe" arguments="--port 6500" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="..\..\..\..\..\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" hostingModel="OutOfProcess"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And I've set system-wide environment variables that look like this:

```
ASPNETCORE_PREFERHOSTINGURLS  -> value = false
ASPNETCORE_URLS  -> value = http://localhost:6500
```

Can anyone provide any input as to why I can't bind Kestrel to a specific port?

Comment: Well, I did not use IIS at all my C# Kestrel api. (I built it off a Jason Watmore example) Some Notes: That if you use both the Listen method and UseUrls, the Listen endpoints override the UseUrls endpoints, and
one hint I found: If you use IIS, the URL bindings for IIS override any bindings that you set by the above two types.

Comment: Nobody can easily explain why, because it might goes deep inside ASP.NET Core module (something written in C++). Most people don't bother by this either, as they use in-process hosting mode.